# Placing random line segments within polygon?

Tags: line, random, azimuth

I would like to generate multiple line segments of a fixed length, a random bearing, and both segment endpoints within the polygon.[image: See example image] 
It's not clear from the example, but it's fine if the segments intersect each other or span the indented features as long as both endpoints are in the polygon.

I also want the attributes table to include lat/lon for each segment endpoint and the azimuth between the endpoints.

Is this possible?

Comment: Good question.  This is certainly possible. However, could you please edit your question to include what software you're using?

Comment: Also, do you have python experience?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python ArcGIS `arcpy` solution. I've optimized this for speed by using [`in_memory`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000005s000000) workspace wherever possible--it is quite fast. This is the general workflow:

1. Negative [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000) the study area by the transect length.
2. [Create Random Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002r000000) inside the negative buffer (study area).
   These will be the starting points for the transects. Note that you can   offset the points n distance from each other if you choose.
3. [Add fields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000047000000) to random points attributes and use a `da` [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) to populate rows with `x`, `y`, `distance`, and `bearing` values.
4. Run [Bearing Distance to Line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/bearing-distance-to-line.htm) to generate the transects.

---

[image]

---

```
import arcpy, os, random

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1

outws = r"C:\path\to\your\filegeodatabase.gdb" # Where the output feature class and table will go. This assumes a file geodatabase
polygon = r"C:\path\to\your\filegeodatabase.gdb\utm15\polygon" # The study area polygon (Note this is in a feature dataset)
transect_distance = 50 # The transect distance
n_lines = 20 # How many transects

# Create random points offset from study area boundary by X distance
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(polygon, "in_memory/buffer", -transect_distance) # negative buffer study area to get correct offset
arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management("in_memory", "rand_points", "in_memory/buffer", "", n_lines)

# Add fields x, y, distance, and bearing
arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "x", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "y", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "distance", "FLOAT")
arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "bearing", "FLOAT")

# Run cursor to update attribute table with pertinent data for bearing distance tool
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("in_memory/rand_points", ["SHAPE@XY", "x", "y", "distance", "bearing"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0][0]
        row[2] = row[0][1]
        row[3] = transect_distance
        row[4] = random.randint(1,360)
        cursor.updateRow(row)

# Create a table to feed to Bearing Distance to line tool
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("in_memory/rand_points",outws,"out_table")

# Generate the transects
arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management (os.path.join(outws, "out_table"), os.path.join(outws, "transects"), x_field = 'x', y_field = 'y', distance_field = 'distance', bearing_field = 'bearing', spatial_reference = "in_memory/rand_points")

# Clean up
arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(outws, "out_table"))

print "Processing complete."
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough stab with R.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
## roughly digitized analog of your map (with raster::drawPoly)

d <- structure(list(x = c(0.08394638623612, 0.0758558910509947, 0.197213318827875, 
0.209349061605562, 0.268005151697721, 0.280140894475409, 0.08394638623612, 
0.08394638623612, 0.112263119384059, 0.120353614569184, 0.112263119384059, 
0.100127376606371, 0.090014257624964, 0.0920368814212453, 0.41767931262254, 
0.454086540955604, 0.454086540955604, 0.462177036140729, 0.504652135862637, 
0.520833126232887, 0.545104611788263, 0.551172483177108, 0.553195106973389, 
0.852543428823026, 0.959742490025936, 0.963787737618499, 0.907154271322622, 
0.909176895118903, 0.937493628266842, 0.955697242433374, 0.941538875859404, 
0.931425756877998, 0.927380509285435, 0.911199518915184, 0.899063776137496, 
0.0859690100324013, 0.08394638623612), y = c(0.0984799434209303, 
0.184633290921423, 0.173297324145043, 0.218641191250565, 0.218641191250565, 
0.352405599211856, 0.356939985922409, 0.522445100857566, 0.529246680923394, 
0.547384227765603, 0.567788967963088, 0.579124934739469, 0.585926514805297, 
0.789973916780149, 0.862524104148985, 0.837584977240947, 0.801309883556529, 
0.767301983227388, 0.751431629740455, 0.762767596516835, 0.776370756648492, 
0.833050590530395, 0.867058490859537, 0.871592877570089, 0.864791297504261, 
0.497505973949529, 0.474834040396767, 0.440826140067625, 0.418154206514864, 
0.418154206514864, 0.313863312172162, 0.273053831777192, 0.216373997895289, 
0.184633290921423, 0.141556617171177, 0.0962127500656542, 0.0984799434209303
)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -37L), class = "data.frame")


## polygon

sp <- raster::spPolygons(cbind(d$x, d$y), attr = data.frame(p = 1))

pts <- spsample(sp, n = 50, type = "random")

## 25 lines
l <- split(as.data.frame(coordinates(pts)), rep(seq(length(pts)/2), each = 2))
lp <- raster::spLines(lapply(l, as.matrix))

op <- par(bg = "black")
plot(sp, border = "yellow", lwd =2 )
plot(lp, add = TRUE, col = "yellow", lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Although, the fixed length requirement does not seem to be satisfied.

Comment: Ah missed that, easy enough to modify though - perhaps use this start as a way to trim to one end or the other. That runs into distribution problems maybe?  Stay tuned