# Generate Random Lines Python Error 000732

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, error-000732

I am trying to generate random lines within a polygon using ArcMap 10.6.1, in the Python window.  I have entered the code that was supplied in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194251/placing-random-line-segments-within-polygon) post and changed the relevant file paths.

Here is the error message:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 15, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3435, in
>   AddField     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset
>   in_memory/rand_points does not exist or is not supported

I'm new to python and can't figure out the error.

Here is the code in it's entirety with error message at the end:

```
>>> import arcpy, os, random
... 
... 
... arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
... 
... 
... outws = r"C:\Users\Leo\GIS\e53f4ad724884ee8a0c033396db0c4f4.gdb"
...  # Where the output feature class and table will go. This assumes a file geodatabase
... 
... 
... polygon = r"C:\Users\Leo\GIS\e53f4ad724884ee8a0c033396db0c4f4.gdb\Humuula" # The study area polygon (Note this is in a feature dataset)
... transect_distance = 50 # The transect distance
... n_lines = 20 # How many transects
... 
... # Create random points offset from study area boundary by X distance
... arcpy.Buffer_analysis(polygon, "in_memory/buffer", -transect_distance) # negative buffer study area to get correct offset
... arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management("in_memory", "rand_points", "in_memory/buffer", "", n_lines)
... 
... # Add fields x, y, distance, and bearing
... arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "x", "DOUBLE")
... arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "y", "DOUBLE")
... arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "distance", "FLOAT")
... arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/rand_points", "bearing", "FLOAT")
... 
... # Run cursor to update attribute table with pertinent data for bearing distance tool
... with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("in_memory/rand_points", ["SHAPE@XY", "x", "y", "distance", "bearing"]) as cursor:
...     for row in cursor:
...         row[1] = row[0][0]
...         row[2] = row[0][1]
...         row[3] = transect_distance
...         row[4] = random.randint(1,360)
...         cursor.updateRow(row)
... 
... # Create a table to feed to Bearing Distance to line tool
... arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("in_memory/rand_points",outws,"out_table")
... 
... # Generate the transects
... arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management (os.path.join(outws, "out_table"), os.path.join(outws, "transects"), x_field = 'x', y_field = 'y', distance_field = 'distance', bearing_field = 'bearing', spatial_reference = "in_memory/rand_points")
... 
... # Clean up
... arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(outws, "out_table"))
... 
... print "Processing complete."
... 
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 20, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3435, in AddField     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset in_memory/rand_points does not exist or is not supported  
>>>
```

Comment: Is your [background processing enabled](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qvnEbH8ANXM/VPmAWGaVw8I/AAAAAAAAAR0/o-gHUs-ixgs/s1600/background_processing_dialog.png)? If so, try to disable it.

Comment: @SonofaBeach I included the code.

Comment: @fatih_dur that was it! Problem solved, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [ESRI product support article](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010149) explains why this error occurs. According to my experience, if you are sure that the data exists (in your case if `arcpy.Exists("in_memory/rand_points")` returns `True`), the usual culprit related to the in_memory workspace is background processing. It is explained in [this help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm#GUID-71C39252-A093-45F9-BA2F-2440274112E8) as well. I would start from here to see if it resolves the issue and, if not, follow the other actions advised in the support page.